# Close second widget after pressing save button pyqt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am writing an application where main widget windows opens second widget window and in the second widget window, I am taking some inputs from user and on hitting save button, second widget window should saves the data into xml file and should get closed but the second window is not closing.
I tried most of the things from google like `self.close(), self.destroy(),self.hide() self.window().hide(), self.window().destroy()` none of them are working.

I don't want to do `sys.exit()` as this is closing complete application  but just have to close secondWidgetWindow after clicking save button so that user can do another work in first widget window.

Below is the snippet :

FirstWidgetWindow.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_firstWidgetWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,firstWidgetWindow):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(firstWidgetWindow)

    def setupUi(self, firstWidgetWindow):
        ### code to create Button ###
        self.btnOpenNewWidgetWindow.clicked.connect(self.openNewWindow)

    def openNewWindow(self):
        self.secondWidgetWindow = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ui = Ui_secondWidgetWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.secondWidgetWindow)
        self.secondWidgetWindow.show()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    firstWidgetWindow = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_firstWidgetWindow(firstWidgetWindow)
    firstWidgetWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

secondWidgetWindow.py

```
class Ui_secondWidgetWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def setupUi(self, secondWidgetWindow):
        ### creating line edit to take input from user
        ### creating save button

        self.btnSave.clicked.connect(self.saveUserInput)

    def saveUserInput(self):
        ## saving user inputs in xml file
        self.close()  ## here i needs to close this window.
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close second widget after pressing save button:

```
self.secondWidgetWindow.hide()
```

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_secondWidgetWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.secondWidgetWindow = None

    def setupUi(self, secondWidgetWindow):
        self.secondWidgetWindow = secondWidgetWindow
        ### creating line edit to take input from user
        self.line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(secondWidgetWindow)
        self.line_edit.setGeometry(20, 20, 300, 20)

        ### creating save button
        self.btnSave = QtWidgets.QPushButton('save', secondWidgetWindow)
        self.btnSave.setGeometry(50, 50, 100, 50)
        self.btnSave.clicked.connect(self.saveUserInput)

    def saveUserInput(self):
        ## saving user inputs in xml file
        #self.close()  ## here i needs to close this window.
        self.secondWidgetWindow.hide()
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "SAVE",
                                        "saving user inputs in xml file")


class Ui_firstWidgetWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,firstWidgetWindow):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(firstWidgetWindow)

    def setupUi(self, firstWidgetWindow):
        ### code to create Button ###
        self.btnOpenNewWidgetWindow = QtWidgets.QPushButton('OpenNewWidgetWindow', firstWidgetWindow)
        self.btnOpenNewWidgetWindow.setGeometry(50, 100, 300, 50)
        self.btnOpenNewWidgetWindow.clicked.connect(self.openNewWindow)

    def openNewWindow(self):
        self.secondWidgetWindow = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ui = Ui_secondWidgetWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.secondWidgetWindow)
        self.secondWidgetWindow.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    firstWidgetWindow = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_firstWidgetWindow(firstWidgetWindow)
    firstWidgetWindow.setGeometry(700, 250, 400, 200)
    firstWidgetWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was thinking the same but I was not knowing how to do it :)

Comment: Hi, I need one more help, on clicking save button second widget should will close and a trigger will be sent to run one function to display the same content( from lineedit of second window ) in the line edit of first window.

Comment: I can’t add code here. Give me an address and I will send you to email

Comment: Thanks a lot :) My mail id is : `kumaravinashse@gmail.com`